# Laravel Mongodb driver error in jenssegers/mongodb package

Tags: laravel, mongodb

[image]I have laravel 5.8 and i have added package jenssegers/mongodb for mongodb. It is showing a error in every page.
I have follow steps present in this site to setup monogodb in laravel.
https://appdividend.com/2018/05/10/laravel-mongodb-crud-tutorial-with-example/

Argument 3 passed to MongoDB\Driver\Server::executeQuery() must be an instance of MongoDB\Driver\ReadPreference or null, array given.
please help me to fix it.

Comment: Show us the code you have used

Comment: did you run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: yes. same error after composer dump-autoload.
same code as written in this link
https://appdividend.com/2018/05/10/laravel-mongodb-crud-tutorial-with-example/

Comment: do you use xampp apache?

Comment: no ubuntu 18.04 with lamp